# Matching string type columns, treating them as comma separated value being matching criteria

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to match two columns from two tables in a join query. for example

```
first_table

+-------+-----------+---------+
|   id  | name      | f_docs  |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   21  |  foo      | 712,7,87|
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   27  |  bar      | 62,31,87|
+-------+-----------+---------+


second_table

+-------+-----------+---------+
|   id  | f_id      | s_docs  |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   44  |  21       | 7,15,22 |
+-------+-----------+---------+
|   49  |  21       | 33,31,98|
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

so from the second I want to get records where f_id = 21 (i.e) and f_docs matches s_docs in regards of the common element 7 in each group taking values as separated by comma is matching criteria.

so it will return first column of the second table as output. So how can achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A guru (e.g. Gordon Linoff) might give an actual solution to this, but the best thing to do would be to do away with that CSV.  It's non-relational, at least from MySQL's point of view, and will make doing the join difficult.

Comment: "do away with that CSV" i know that but it's not my option now, so asked here.

Comment: If `second_table` had single values in `s_docs`, then you could use `FIND_IN_SET()` and it would not be so bad.

Comment: You can create a temporary table based on `second_table` where the `s_docs` CSV values are exploded each into its own record, and then join this to `first_table` using `FIND_IN_SET()`

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that idea of temporary table's structure?@TimBiegeleisen